# How to apply a SilverStripe extension last?

Tags: yaml, silverstripe

I have a specific module that does a few things to tidy up the CMS.
Let's call it `silverstripe-cleanup`.

One of the things this module does is move the `MetaData` fields to their own tab which I want to **always** be the final tab in the CMS.

So if my `/httpdocs/silverstripe-cleanup/config/config.yml` looks as shown below, how do I ensure this extension is applied after all others?

```
---
Name: silverstripe-cleanup
---

SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - MetaDataMovementExtension
```

Comment: I **think** you can do
`---
Name: silverstripe-cleanup
After: "*"
---`

Answer (score 3):

To make a module the last one to load we can add something like `After: "*"` to our module `config.yml` file:

```
---
Name: silverstripe-cleanup
After: "*"
---

SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - MetaDataMovementExtension
```

This should ensure this module is called after all others.

This still may not load after all fields and tabs are added to a page's CMS fields. This is because of the point at which `updateCMSFields` is called in a page's `getCMSFields` function.

Say this is our `updateCMSFields` function:

```
class MetaDataMovementExtension extends Extension {

    function updateCMSFields($fields) {
        if ($metadataFields = $fields->fieldByName('Root.Main.Metadata')) {
            $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Main', 'Metadata');
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Metadata', $metadataFields);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is one of our classes:

```
class HomePage extends Page {

    // ...

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $slidesField = GridField::create(
            'Slides',
            'Slide',
            $this->Slides(),
            GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
        );
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', $slidesField);

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Column', TextField::create('ColumnTitle', 'Title'));

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

The `updateCMSFields` hook gets called in [`SiteTree::getCMSFields`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/source-class-SiteTree.html#2033). Looking at our `getCMSFields` function above, the `updateCMSFields` function will be called at the top of our function at the point that we call `parent::getCMSFields()`. After that we then add extra fields. This means our extension will get called before we add extra fields. These extra fields will be placed after our moved metadata tab.

What we can do is wrap our additional fields in each of our `getCMSFields` with [`beforeUpdateCMSFields`](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/#object-extension-injection-points):

```
    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $self =& $this;
        $this->beforeUpdateCMSFields(function ($fields) use ($self) {

            $slidesField = new GridField(
                'Slides',
                'Slide',
                $self->Slides(),
                GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
            );
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Slides', $slidesField);

            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Column', TextField::create('ColumnTitle', 'Title'));
        });

        return parent::getCMSFields();
    }
```

This will ensure that our fields are added before `updateCMSFields` is called.

An important thing to note when using `beforeUpdateCMSFields` is that we need to use `$self` instead of `$this` inside our `beforeUpdateCMSFields` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Before: and After: constructs from the config header section (the bits between the --- lines before the definitions).

cf. The default mysite one from silverstripe/installer for hints.

Comment: I've tried doing that although I always get confused with Before:/After: but I have another module that adds in another tab, so I tried doing both variants of (with appropriate indentation/new lines) `Before: - 'other-module'` and `After: - 'other-module'` to no effect. the only time I did manage to get anything out of it was when I replace `'other-module'` with `'*'` on one of them but that simply threw an error saying it had been asked to run both before and after something, which nothing else referenced this module directly so I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked just the opposite way, i.e. changing After for Before.
I wanted to have an extension from 'mymodule' loaded after an extension from 'anothermodule' and firstly I had:

```
---
Name: mymodule           # (it is also in mymodule/)
After:
  - "anothermodule/*"    # (this is also in anothermodule/)
---
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - MyModuleSiteConfigExtension
```

However it did not work so I tried:

```
---
Name: mymodule
Before:
  - "anothermodule/*"
---
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - MyModuleSiteConfigExtension
```

After this change the loading order seemed proper for me (AnotherModuleSiteConfigExtension, MyModuleSiteConfigExtension), I do not know why it goes against all of my understanding..
So in your case you could try this maybe?

```
---
Name: silverstripe-cleanup
Before: "*"
---

SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - MetaDataMovementExtension
```